# Conditionally create URLwith php and pass to jquery.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page with an ajax form and want to control which form the user is served based on an url argument. I can read the url arg and decide which form the user needs but cannot figure out how to pass the url from php to javascript.

for example the user visits page based on `example.com/index.php?utm_source=test`

Then I check for the code and define the form the user should use

```
$utm_source = $_GET['utm_source'];

if ($utm_source = 'test'){
  $formList='list[4]';
  $formUrl= 'https://www.example.com/?p=asubscribe&id=4' ;
  }
else {
  $formList="list[2]";
  $formUrl="https://www.example.com/?p=asubscribe&id=2";
```

Still in the header I add the url to ajax using `json_encode`

```
function submitForm() {
  successMessage =
    "success.";
  data = jQuery("#subscribeform").serialize();
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url: <?php echo json_encode("$formUrl") ?>;,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data, status, request) {
      jQuery("#result")
        .empty()
        .append(data != "" ? data : successMessage);
      jQuery("#email").val("");
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
      alert("error.");
    },
  });
}
```

However the url that is generated is `https:\/\/www.example.com\/?p=asubscribe&id=4`

I also try the `http_build_query($data)` but it doesn't include the https://domain, the form needs full url.

How can I fix the `\/\/` issues so it's a valid URL?

Comment: You don't have to use `<?php echo json_encode("$formUrl") ?>` - just do `url: "<?php echo $formUrl; ?>", `.

Comment: Is there any good reason for encoding the URL? Why not use `url: "<?php echo $formUrl; ?>", `

Comment: @NicoHaase you tell me, I read on another question that it was compulsory when working from php to ajax/javascript/jquery. Evidently I'm mistaken.

Comment: @verjas so easy.. jajaja, thank you

Comment: I don't know which other question you've read, but there might be some kind of misunderstanding: if there are variables to be appended to an URL, they should be encoded, but not the URL itself